# API call returns the json string twice

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to return a `json` string in `Flutter`. I'm using the `print` function to display the output in the console. However my code is returning the `String` twice. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() => runApp(new HomePage());

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {



  Future<http.Response> fetchPost() async{
    return await http.get('https://api.npoint.io/8c7aafe809d73af5f2b9');
  }


  void Data() async {
    var jsonString = await fetchPost();
    print(jsonString.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Data();
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Center(
        child: new Text('Data'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build method is called twice causing the whole widget to be called again. Consider converting `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and add your http call method in

```dart
@overridde 
initState() {
    your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved using `try` `catch`

```
Future<http.Response> fetchPost() async{
try{
return await http.get('https://api.npoint.io/8c7aafe809d73af5f2b9');
}
catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
    
  }
```